# OpenCV 3D reconstruction with 1 camera

Tags: opencv, 3d

Playing with **stereo 3D reconstruction** using one camera and rotating the object, but I can't seem to get proper Z mapping.

I follow the typical process: 
**calibrate** the camera with the chessboard, get the camera *matrix* and *distorsion*. 
Take *left* and *right* images by rotation the object, *undistort* the images.
All this seems fine to me. The images look good.

I get the disparity map with `StereoBM.compute` on the left and right images.

There is some black areas but mostly gray, so the Z seems to be computed for most of the image.

then I use `stereoRectify` to get the **Q matrix**:
I use a rotation matrix which I built using `Rodrigues` on a rotation vector.

My rotation is only along the Y axis, so the rotation vector is `[0, angle, 0]` (angle being the angle by which the object was rotated)
The Rotation matrix seems right as far as I can tell: I tried with trivial angles and I get what is expected.

I also need the translation vector, so I used `[cos(angle), 0, sin(angle)]`
since I rotate only along Y, I then have a translation of the camera by the arc of the rotation.

I use stereoRectify with the same camera matrix and distortion for both cameras since it is the same camera.

when i `reprojectImageTo3D` with **Q** and the **disparity** map, I get a result that looks OK in Meshlab when looking at the right angle, but the depth seems way off when I move around (i.e the Z depth of the object is ~2x the width, when the object is really 1/10th of the width)

So, I'm just wondering if this is normal, and expected because it's only 2 images from a ~20degree angle difference, or if I'm just messing up somewhere. Especially I wonder if I need to account somewhere for the distance from the camera to the center of rotation of the object: I believe the Rotation matrix and translation vector should be taking care of that, but it's on a unit basis.

I know it is a bit of a vague question, but I hope someone can confirm or infirm my assumptions here.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit more thinking, I understand why this doesn't work:

my virtual stereo camera vanishing point is basically at the center of rotation of the object, when the algorithms assume it is at infinity.

stereoRectify can't transform my near-focus vanishing point into infinity.

furthermore the disparity map assumes a horizontal shift to recalculate Z depth. In my case, the shift is not a horizontal translation but due to a rotation in-plane, which just doesn't work.